# converting <> operator to python3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, operators

I am trying to convert this [feedparser.py](https://github.com/Unode/python-feedparser/blob/master/feedparser/feedparser.py) (on github) to python3.  I am having trouble understanding what this line is doing, right now it throws a syntax error:

```
[line 640]   if tag.find(':') <> -1:
```

what operator is `<>`.  Is there a Python3 equivalent?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a synonym for the inequality operator, `!=`, as seen in BASIC.

By the way, the line you are asking about would be far more idiomatically written as:

```
if ":" in tag:
```

Answer (score 7):

It's an old spelling of the inequality comparison. [Use `!=` instead.](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#removed-syntax)

Answer (score 5):

`<>` is read 'not equals'
`!=` will do the same